# Why doesn't my Javascript run?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried Google for an answer to this and others have looked at my work but we can't understand what is wrong here ......?  My HTML displays correctly but my Javascript does not run?  I am new to Javascript so please explain things simply!  My Javascript is in a separate stylesheet from my HTML.

```js
var name;

document.getElementById("changeName").onclick = newName;

function newName() {
  name = prompt("What is your name?");
  updateName();
}

function updateName() {
  document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = name;
}

var item1;
var item2;
var item3;

document.getElementById("changeList").onclick = newList;

function newList() {
  item1 = prompt("Enter a new first thing: ");
  item2 = prompt("Enter a new second thing: ");
  item3 = prompt("Enter a new third thing: ");
  updateList();
}

function updateList() {
  document.getElementById("firstThing").innerHTML = item1;
  document.getElementById("secondThing").innerHTML = item2;
  document.getElementById("thirdThing").innerHTML = item3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Things I Like</title>
    <style type="text/javascript" src="JS/javascript.js"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="myName">Elizabeth</h1>
    <button id="changeName" type="button">Add Your Name</button>
    <hr>
    <p id="aboutMe">I'm learning to build dynamic pages with JavaScript and HTML!</p>
    <hr>
    <h1>Things I Like</h1>
    <p>Here are some of the things I like to do:</p>
    <ol>
      <li id="firstThing">Write JavaScript</li>
      <li id="secondThing">Travel the world</li>
      <li id="thirdThing">See my friends</li>
    </ol>
    <button id="changeList" type="button">Change Your List</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a <style> tag that points to a javascript file which should probably be <script> instead.

Comment: Your java script is not stylesheet you need to change it <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/javascript.js"></script >

Comment: because you should use script, no style... `<script src="script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript doesn't go in "stylesheets". It goes in script files.

This:

```
<style type="text/javascript" src="JS/javascript.js"></style>
```

is wrong. Instead you want this:

```
<script src="JS/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: At least, I edit the question before answer.... ;) The easiest 70 reputation points you earn!

Comment: It still will not run.

Comment: @epascarello It will break due to them trying to access DOM elements before they're ready but the script will run.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, but javascript it's not stylesheet, that's CSS.

Change this:

```
 <style type="text/javascript" src="JS/javascript.js"></style>
```

With this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/javascript.js"></script>
```

And it works.

Comment: It still will not work

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the `<style>`/`<script>` error...

Web pages are loaded top down. So what happens is your JavaScript is loaded and run first. In the second line of your JavaScript you try to get an HTML element.

The problem is the HTML element doesn't exist yet because the web browser hasn't loaded/rendered the HTML yet.

This will not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Things I Like</title>
        <script>
            var dingo = document.getElementById("dingo")
            // this will not work because the HTML hasn't finished loading and rendering so the DIV doesn't exist yet
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dingo">ate my baby</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Things I Like</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dingo">ate my baby</div>
        <script>
            var dingo = document.getElementById("dingo")
            // this will work
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```